# fixed-point data type integer precision range (12 bit) in CG

Tags: integer, opencl, gpu, nvidia, type-conversion

the wiki article currently has a very clear description of half precision floating point integer range(16-bit):

Integers between 0 and 2048 can be exactly represented.....
Integers between 2049 and 4096 round to a multiple of 2 (even number).....
Integers between 4097 and 8192 round to a multiple of 4.....
Integers between 8193 and 16384 round to a multiple of 8.....
Integers between 16385 and 32768 round to a multiple of 16.....
Integers between 32769 and 65536 round to a multiple of 32.....
Integers equal to or above 65520 are rounded to "infinity"......

However, for fixed point integers I couldn't find practical information about integer range on the web, it can represent integers exactly up to 32? 64?

And it says that half precision, 0 01111 0000000001 = 1 + 2−10 = 1.0009765625 (next smallest float after 1)

Could someone even say the equivalent decimal for fixed point datatypes? esp. in CG code.

Thanks!

Comment: I found a little bit info: fixed: low precision fixed point. Generally 11 bits, with a range of -2.0 to +2.0 and 1/256th precision... except its essentially an integer, I read somewhere else. so must be higher than 2 on GPUs?

Answer (score 2):

There is no single implementation of fixed-point values, and the range of integers that can be represented is different for each implementation. For a 12-bit signed fixed-point representation, the implementer may choose to use none of those bits to represent the integer part of the number and use 11 bits for the fractional part. In that case the range is (approximately) -1 to +1. On the other hand, using all 11 bits to represent the integer part and none of the bits to represent the fractional part is still a valid fixed-point number. For that case the range is \$-2^{11}\$ to \$2^{11}-1\$. So, the number of bits used to represent the integer can be any value from 0 to 11 for a 12-bit signed number.

Furthermore, it is not necessarily true that all of the variables in a given function or block of code will have the same fixed-point format. Different variables may have a different number of bits used for representing the integer part, even if the word length is fixed.

Comment: Thankyou. by forgot to say that I was thinking about CG code. I thought that datatypes were always dynamic and they represented the highest and lowest numbers with as many bits as they have.